# unlimited stack of tile(object/sprite) in que after dragging the first to toppest one in phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

i am making a game using phaser and i want to make unlimited no of tiles can think like stacked tiles. When the user drags the topmost tile and places it in the drop area, the same tile below it should appear and should be draggable.

My present code:- `

```
var greenTile = this.add.sprite(250,500,'greenTile');       
                   greenTile.inputEnabled=true;
                   greenTile.input.enableDrag();
                   greenTile.events.onDragStart.add(onDragStart, this);
                   greenTile.events.onDragStop.add(onDragStop, this);`
```

the total code is of my game state is :- 
`

```
var patternsRatio = patternsRatio || {};
var x = 50;
var y = 100;
var canvas;
var canvasBG;
var canvasGrid;
var canvasSprite;
var canvasZoom = 32;
var spriteWidth = 8;
var spriteHeight = 8;
patternsRatio.game1 = function () {};
patternsRatio.game1.prototype = {           
    preload: function () {
    this.load.image('greenTile','assets/images/greentile.png')
    this.load.image('redTile','assets/images/redtile.png')
    },
    create: function () {
        this.game.stage.setBackgroundColor(0x2d2d2d);
        var question_l1 = "Puzzle 1: Enlarge this pattern by a factor of 2."
        var style_l1 = {font: "25px Comic Sans MS Bold", fill: "#fff", align:"center"}; 
        var quet_l1=this.game.add.text(this.game.world.centerX,this.game.height-600, question_l1, style_l1)
        quet_l1.anchor.setTo(0.5)
        this.placetiles()

        var greenTile = this.add.sprite(250,500,'greenTile');       
        greenTile.inputEnabled=true;
        greenTile.input.enableDrag();
        greenTile.events.onDragStart.add(onDragStart, this);
        greenTile.events.onDragStop.add(onDragStop, this);

        var redTile = this.add.sprite(100,500,'redTile');
        redTile.inputEnabled=true;
        redTile.input.enableDrag();
        redTile.events.onDragStart.add(onDragStart, this);
        redTile.events.onDragStop.add(onDragStop, this);


},
    update: function () {

},  
    placetiles: function () {
        this.game.create.grid('drawingGrid', 16 * canvasZoom, 16 * canvasZoom, canvasZoom, canvasZoom, 'rgba(0,191,243,0.8)');
        canvas = this.game.make.bitmapData(spriteWidth * canvasZoom, spriteHeight * canvasZoom);
        canvasBG = this.game.make.bitmapData(canvas.width + 2, canvas.height + 2);

        canvasBG.rect(0, 0, canvasBG.width, canvasBG.height, '#fff');
        canvasBG.rect(1, 1, canvasBG.width - 2, canvasBG.height - 2, '#3f5c67');

        var x = 80;
        var y = 64;

        canvasBG.addToWorld(x, y);
        canvasSprite = canvas.addToWorld( x + 1, y + 1); canvasZoom,canvasZoom
        canvasGrid = this.game.add.sprite(x + 1, y + 1, 'drawingGrid');
        canvasGrid.crop(new Phaser.Rectangle(0, 0, spriteWidth * canvasZoom, spriteHeight * canvasZoom));

        }

};

`
```

I am also facing problem when i am adding a input.enable code below the "greenTile" variable then the redTile vanishes of can any tell why this happens.
[In the image below as we can see both red and green tile are appearing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT2Z2.png)

[In this image as we can i had added input enable and the red Tile stopped appearing, Secondly as  have dragged the green tile to the grid, i want on the original place their should be again the greenTile should come.(this is in reference to the stack able unlimited tile question)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxMRc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could figure this out by just adding a function and calling it on the drag start event as below:-

The function that i added is :-

```
addGreenTiles: function(){

    this.greenTile1 = this.add.sprite(250,500,'greenTile');
    this.greenTile1.inputEnabled=true;
    this.greenTile1.input.enableSnap(canvasZoom, canvasZoom, false, true);
    this.greenTile1.input.enableDrag();
    this.greenTile1.originalPosition = this.greenTile1.position.clone();
    this.greenTile1.events.onDragStart.add(this.addGreenTiles, this);
    this.greenTile1.events.onDragStop.add(function(currentSprite){
            this.stopDrag(currentSprite, this.greenTile1);
}, this);
```

Then i called this function at :

```
this.greenTile1.events.onDragStart.add(this.addGreenTiles, this);
```